# How can I remove a burden of removing trailing commas in package.json of Node.js project?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am currently adding dummy keys at end of json objects in package.json, as in the following example.

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "": ""
  },
  "": ""
}
```

I am not certain this ugly hack will not be broken in the future.
Is there more proper or stable method to deal with trailing commas?

Comment: Just don't use trailing commas to begin with, I'd think

Comment: Why are they there in the first place? It’s not valid JSON. Some formatters may be able to fix this automatically, even if it means temporarily making it JS and running it through with a no-trailing-commas rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a code formatter like [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) which will take care of deleting trailing commas in JSON file or add them in JS files (if you want them, depending on your configuration). There are plugins for IDEs so that it runs every time you save your files.